# Pagination in search results

Tags: 7, search

I have installed [search configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config) module to alter pagination on search results. I've set the pager limit in *Configuration > Search settings > ADDITIONAL NODE SEARCH CONFIGURATION > RESULTS* to 3 (which should trigger pagination), but no pagination is appearing when I am logged in whereas when I am logout, it is showing pagination having 2 items per page instead of 3.

Comment: how many items are you showing / or are published? maybe you can't see them because they are not published for anon users?

Answer (score 0):

This is, presumably, by design. If you look at Search Config's [query alter function](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/search_config/tree/search_config.module?h=7.x-1.x#n149), you can see that the function returns (without limiting results) if you're you're the superuser. Hence, when you're logged in with UID = 1 you will not see the pagination.

Comment: Oh, thanku. @shawn I have edited my question, because when I am logout I can see the pagination but not the right one.2 items per page are displaying instead of 3.Do you have any idea about it.